# PHP preg_replace replace wildcard string with html and what happens after the wildcard

Tags: php, regex

Hey I have a hard time understanding regex but I think that what suits my needs best currently have this line:

```
    $str = preg_replace('/https:\/\/clips.twitch.tv\/(.*?)/', '<iframe src="https://clips.twitch.tv/embed?autoplay=false&clip=$1&tt_content=embed&tt_medium=clips_embed" width="640" height="360" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" allowfullscreen="true"></iframe>', $text);
```

What I want is to replace f.ex this link:

```
https://clips.twitch.tv/GleamingHelpfulOxNotLikeThis
```

To be the HTML in the replace part, but the last part f.ex. `GleamingHelpfulOxNotLikeThis` ends up behind the iframe and not after `clip=` where I have `$1` which I thought would work.

Comment: Replace `(.*?)` with `([^\/]+)`

Comment: Thanks almost, somehow I get one ">" inside it now it reads "GleamingHelpfulOxNotLikeThis<" now

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew That's not right. There's no `/` after the URL.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php

Comment: You didn't show us `$text`

Comment: $text is the link https://clips.twitch.tv/GleamingHelpfulOxNotLikeThis

Comment: Are you just trying to insert a string into a template? What are you *actually* trying to accomplish? Explain it without using the word "regex".

Comment: I have that link and I want to convert it to the html that it's replaced with in the function. $text doesn't just have to be a link it could be alot more text but for now I just have a link as example.

Comment: The you only need to replace `(.*?)` with `(.*)`

Comment: Somehow it seems that text ends with a </p> too so I don't want that included. Cause now the src becomes https://clips.twitch.tv/embed?autoplay=false&clip=GleamingHelpfulOxNotLikeThis</p>&tt_content=embed&tt_medium=clips_embed with the </p>

Comment: I asked a lot for your real `$text`. I knew something.

Comment: I thought my text was just the link but it was for a wordpress function and it somewhat unexpectedly added the p-tags without my knowledge.

Comment: As soon as you realize that your posted data fails to express your project data, you should edit your post.  This allows volunteers to accurately provide the best suited solution.  When we have to guess or make assumptions, the value of the entire page is impacted.   Not only will the answers be of questionable value to you, the page will be of questionable value to future researchers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.*?` will match everything after the domain name, so you're including the entire rest of the line in your match. Making it non-greedy with `?` doesn't help, because there's nothing after the wildcard that will cause it to stop.

If the last part of the URL is just an alphanumeric string, use `\w*` instead of `.*`.

If that's not how these URLs are constructed, you need to find some other way of telling where the URL ends in the text. This is not trivial, and often requires heuristics that misbehave. URLs can use most characters without requiring any escaping, including most punctuation, but when people type them into free-flowing text they'll often put punctuation after them and intend it to be distinguished. For instance, someone might write:

```
Is the URL http://www.foo.com/foobarbaz?
```

They intend the `?` to mark it as a question, so that the URL ends at `foobarbaz`, but `?` is a valid (and common) character in a URL, so there's no reason why `http://www.foo.com/foobarbaz?` couldn't be the intended URL. As humans we generally have no problem figuring this out from context, but a simple regular expression would have little hope. I've seen many automatic URL recognizers mess up like this.

So you should be prepared for the possibility that no matter what you use as the regexp, it might not parse all URLs correctly unless there are restrictions on the URLs that can be used.

Comment: Dunno why someone downvoted this. \w* was exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @indiehjaerta It was not my downvote, but you will find that some users will downvote answer that answer an Unclear question or when the provided answer is likely to break when the input string changes slightly.  You have not represented your sample input string very well and we don't know how your data may vary.  It is entirely possible that `\w` will not be effective when your input changes.

Comment: @mickmackusa I've added some discussion of the limitations of this type of thing.